# How to get all EC2s information for all Accounts in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have Master account and  multiple Accounts under Master account in AWS,  and I need the Operating System, Version of Operating of System and Build Version of the Operating System for All the ec2s for all Accounts .

Comment: Read up on AWS Systems Manager.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use AWS System Manager inventory function to keep track of an inventory.  See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/systems-manager-inventory.html

AWS System manager will be able to collect data about instances in your AWS account and in other AWS accounts.